# If somebody is banned from asking a question from a certain site, but can edit their older questions, what does it mean?

Tags: discussion, questions

So say I'm banned from the Limguistics forum and can't post new questions but I CAN edit the older questions. Can I just edit them entirely, like just change them into a whole new question?

Answer (score 1):

[You can find full details in the Help Center.](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)

The way to lift a question ban is to edit your existing questions, but **not** to just delete them and replace them with new questions. You'll need to find ways to improve the questions while keeping their essence intact.

You can also earn some reputation from answering questions, which will help lift the ban.

Comment: The only time it's okay to completely change a question is if it's closed and has zero answers. Then it's not hurting anything to change it totally.

Comment: @curiousdannii If that's our policy, I'd recommend posting it as a separate answer so OP sees it. (I have no objection to it.)

Comment: Probably more of an exception to the policy! When people have been question banned before that's what I've suggested to help them. They don't usually take up the offer though.

Comment: @curiousdannii Either way, probably best to make sure it sends a notification to OP.

Answer (score 0):

Curiousdannii, another mod, has also said it's fine to completely replace questions that are closed with no answers.

Comment: I fixed one: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/46654/why-does-the-letter-k-make-atleast-two-sounds-in-languages-like-norwegian-swe

Comment: I fixed another one:                      https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/46690/controversies-of-indonesian-and-malay-spelling